# Set max/min dates on jQuery UI DatePicker on the fly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two jQuery calendars that are shown all the time on screen.  I want the `maxDate` of the first calendar to be the date of the second, and the `minDate` of the second to be the date of the first.

I can currently see no way of modifying `minDate` and `maxDate` on the fly (i.e. through the `onSelect` property).  How can I get the effect I want?

Pseudo code:

```
$("#date1").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        //Set minDate property on #date2 to selectedDate
    }
});

$("#date2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        //Set maxDate property  on #date1 to selectedDate
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) you need to:

```
// setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
```

So

```
$("#date2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
         $( "#date1" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `minDate` and `maxDate` programmatically like this:

```
$("#date2").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#date1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(selectedDate));
    }
});
```

Here is the [**documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) for min/maxDate.

Comment: Won't that recreate the original datepicker on "#date1"?

Comment: the docs say 'Get or set the minDate option, after initialization:' use my post method :)

Comment: @Chris, sorry I copied the wrong statement from the docs, see my update.